# How to configure the authentication in spring data with mongodb (Spring-config.xml)

Tags: xml, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

How to configure the authentication in  spring data with mongodb (Spring-config.xml)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo-client credentials="admin:admin@admin" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="itsadmin" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here this is my spring-config.xml but i am getting issues

Answer (score 1):

Add following dependency in pom.xml

```
    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring data mongodb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring-config

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<mongo:mongo-client host="${mongo.url}" port="${mongo.port}" credentials="${mongo.user}:${mongo.pass}@${mongo.dbname}">
    <mongo:client-options write-concern="NORMAL" />
</mongo:mongo-client>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.dbname}"/>
</bean>
```

In java code you can get mongoTemplate like this:

```
   @Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public String mongoTest() {

    DBCollection dc = mongoTemplate.getCollection("yourCollection");

    logger.debug("--get collection name=" + dc.getFullName());

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i want how to give credentials in spring-config.xml (Username and password) . I am using mongo-java driver 3.1.0 and spring -data mongodb release 1.9.1.

Comment: Iam not using any mongo template class in myproject